# Можно ли с помощью JavaScript получить доступ к уведомлению о разрешениях на доступ к функционалу Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Можно ли получить доступ к уведомлению, которое отображено на скрине ниже, через JS, чтобы дать разрешение,.. то есть проще говоря, нажать с помощью JS кнопку `Allow`?:

[image: www.google.com wants to "Know your location"]

Comment: Вообще-то только за такие попытки нужно давать по рукам

Comment: @SanyaH, это автотесты.

Comment: Поэтому, ищите, как включить|выключить локацию для chrome/chrome driver. Например, --disable-geolocation

Comment: @KoVadim, я пробовал `--disable-search-geolocation-disclosure`: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-search-geolocation-disclosure, но не проходит ...